# Rails Asset Pipeline Better Error or Stack Trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Just upgraded an app from rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.1 and when i run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get errors, which is fine however the backtrace doesn't tell me where in my css or scss files the syntax problem is coming from. I tried greping for "0ee5c0e69c92af0" but that string doesn't appear in my project.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...0ee5c0e69c92af0": expected ";", was ".png;"
```

Is there a way to get a better error message or stack trace from the precompilation process? Is there another way I can compile my `css.erb` files to check for syntax without this task?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a better way that I know of, because this message is generated by Sprockets (actually the CSS processor) after it has concatenated all the files together.

One thing you could do (temporarily) is replace the default precompile array in application.rb with this:

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.css']
```

Then remove any requires from your application.css and run the precompile task locally. This will compile each CSS file individually, and hopefully give you more clues as to where the problem is.

Comment: I was able to grep around for the second part looking for `.png;` rather than the hash which is apparently auto-generated, and fix the issue. I think this method would work, though I wish the default gave better errors.

Comment: perhaps you could file a bug with the Sprockets project to provide more context for such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, pass the --trace flag to rake:

```
$ bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
```

Comment: Oops, it fell off the edge of text area.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I was upgrading to the asset pipeline as well, and here was the culprit for me. When you add the asset pipeline, its important to also transition your stylesheets from using url (this one points to the non-fingerprinted/non-cached file in the asset pipeline) to the new image-url helper (this one points to the fingerprinted/cached file in the asset pipeline). See Section 2.3 in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Pre-asset pipeline(.sass):

```
#background
  background-image: url('Long Path 1920x1200.jpg')
```

Post-asset pipeline(.sass):

```
#background
  background-image: image-url('Long Path 1920x1200.jpg')
```

Unfortunately, the new image-url helper cannot deal with spaces in a file name, while the old url could. So, it will go boom when you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. The solution is to remove the spaces.

Corrected code:

```
#background
  background-image: image-url('long-path-1920x1200.jpg')
```